# C++ adding numbers from one array to the other

Tags: c++, arrays

i'm newbie in C++ programing.
i got problems whit adding number from array B to array A.
if B / A = 0. i need to add number B just behind the number A in array.

my adding function is :

```
**void adding (int A[], int B[], int & n, int m)
{
    int next = 0;
   for(int i = m; i > 1; i --)
   {
       for(int j = n; j > 1; j--)
       {
           if(B[i] / A[i] == 0)
           {
               next = A[i];
            A[i] = A[i-1];
            B[i] = A[i+1];

           }
       }
   }
}**
```

Comment: Be specific about what the problem is, and only post a small amount of code that shows the problem.

Comment: Try to specify the problem. May be elaborate a further more what do you want by editing the code.

Comment: I don't see A and B getting added.

Comment: i think i dont add the number because i need to find the number A index in array A. yes? 
so basically i need to make other function called indexfinding. i'm right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no math operators defined for an array as a whole.

If you need to perform operations on an array as a whole, consider using matrices.

**Element By Element**
Array operations are performed element by element.  You would retrieve one array element and perform an operation on the second element.

Example:  Sum.
If I want to add the odd elements of A to the even elements of B and place into an Array, I would do the following:

```
int A[20];
int B[20];
int C[20];
//...
C[0] = A[0] + B[1];
C[1] = A[2] + B[3];
C[2] = A[4] + B[5];
//...
```

Studying this example, it can be placed into a `for` loop.

You should first develop code or an algorithm that specifically calls out each element, then place into a `for` loop.

This is as much help as I can give you since you did not supply, in your post, a formula or math expression explaining how the result is calculated.